# Error when display view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I compile my program I have this error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' does not
>   contain a definition for 'WIE_Ilosc' and no extension method
>   'WIE_Ilosc' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What must I change in my code to make it work correctly?

my view:

```
@model List<Webb.Models.Faktury>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Faktura VAT</h2>
    <p>
        Oryginal</p>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Data S.</td>
            <td>Numer</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.FAK_Id</td>
                <td>@item.FAK_DataS</td>
                <td>@item.Firma.FIR_Rachunek</td>
                <td>@item.Wierszes.WIE_Ilosc</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

my controller:

```
public ActionResult Reports(int? id)
        {
            // Setup sample model
            var pro = (from a in db.Fakturies
                       join b in db.Wierszes on a.FAK_Id equals b.WIE_Fkid
                       join c in db.Produkties on b.WIE_Pid equals c.PRO_Id
                       select a);

            pro = pro.Where(a => a.FAK_Id == id);

            if (Request.QueryString["format"] == "pdf")
                return new PdfResult(pro.ToList(), "Reports");

            return View(pro);
        }
```

Part of model:

```
public Faktury()
        {
            this.Wierszes = new HashSet<Wiersze>();
        }
     .
     .
     .
     .

        public virtual ICollection<Wiersze> Wierszes { get; set; }
        public virtual Firma Firma { get; set; }
        public virtual Klienci Klienci { get; set; }
        public virtual Statusy Statusy { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at this line in your razor code.

```
<td>@item.Wierszes.WIE_Ilosc</td>
```

But as per your class definition, `Wierszes` property on the `Faktury` class is a collection type (`ICollection<Wiersze>`). In your view you are trying to access the `WIE_Ilosc` property on the collection !

If you want to show all the Wiersze's, you should loop through them again and render it.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <tr>
       <td>@item.FAK_Id</td>
       <td>@item.FAK_DataS</td>
       <td>
            @if(item.Wierszes!=null)
            {
               foreach(var v in item.Wierszes)
               {
                   <span>@v.WIE_Ilosc</span>
               }
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Since Wierszes isn't projected in the Linq query wouldn't `item.Wierszes` always be null

Comment: Faktury has this `Wierszes` property and lazy loading might give him the data. Haven't used EF in a while :)